# Playlist ascending / descending resetting

Tags: itunes

I'm using iTunes version 12.6.2.20 (latest) with a combination of local music, Apple Music, and iCloud Music Library.

In iTunes, all playlists are always sorted correctly except for "Current Favourites" which is supposed to be sorted ascending but always reverts to descending on restart of iTunes or the PC. This ascending / descending reversion affects all playlists.

On my iPhone, the playlists are always sorted correctly including "Current Favourites".

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that upgrading to version 12.7.0.166 and/or using option `View` | `Show View Options` | `Sort By` has resolved the issue.